# JavaScript and JQuery Accessing HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML file in which I import JQuery as well as my own Javascript file. When I put:

```
<script>
$( "#htmlID" ).click(function() {
  $( "#htmlID" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

in my HTML file and then click on the "htmlID" div in question, it successfully hides it. However, when I put:

```
$( "#htmlID" ).click(function() {
  $( "#htmlID" ).hide();
});
```

in my Javascript file, it doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: Put your javascript file after your jQuery import script tag.

Comment: For debugging, check the browser console.

Comment: Those three lines will run immediately, so if you put them above the actual div, they won't have any effect. Wrap your code in `$(function() {` and `});` - this makes it run after all HTML has loaded.

Comment: tried to put it inside a document.ready?

Comment: Please check the below answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap it into following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#htmlID" ).click(function() {
      $( "#htmlID" ).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the HTML document that the code which is going to execute is a script. Scripts segments can be made part of the document. When DOM finds a script section, it deals with it as an executable part of page, and executes that code.

You can put it as function in your javascript file, call it from inside $(document).ready function on the page.

Code inside script file is not automatically executed, unless you are putting it as IIFE(immediately invoked function expression). If you want to use javascript file, you can put it inside IIFE.

```
$(function(){
  $( "#htmlID" ).click(function() {
  $( "#htmlID" ).hide();
});
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the jquery call first and then include your custom js file like this:

```
<div id="htmlID">
Html ID element
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

In your custom js you can give:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#htmlID").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
  })
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ud0y0g6a/